# Send attachment in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I want to send an attachment with email. Till now I am able to send the attachment with mail but the problem is when I am downloading attachment it will show HTML code of my login page.

Please help me to figure it out why attachment show loging page data

Below is my code for **compose.blade**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ action('ServiceRequestEmailController@store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="mt20 clearfix text-right action-btn-btm">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button> &nbsp;
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url('superadmin/service-request/view/' . $ServiceRequest->id) }}">Discard</a>
                    <div class=" border-bottom"></div>
                </div>
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input type="hidden" name="sr_id" value="{{ $ServiceRequest->id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $mail->getParentId() }}" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="{{ $mail->getAction() }}" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="email">Service Request:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6"><a href="{{ url('superadmin/service-request/view/' . $ServiceRequest->id) }}"><span>{{ $ServiceRequest->id }}</span></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2">Consultant  Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6"> <span>{{ $ServiceRequest->name }}</span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2">Consultant  Code:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6"> <span>{{ $ServiceRequest->mca_no }}</span> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="from">From:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" name="from">
                            @foreach ( $mail->from() as $email )
                                <option>{{ $email }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group autocomplete-to">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="to">To:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to" id="to" value="{{ old('to') ?: $mail->to() }}" />
                        @if ($errors->has('to.*'))
                            <p class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('to.*') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group autocomplete-to">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input  col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="cc">Cc:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cc" id="cc" value="{{ old('cc') ?: $mail->cc() }}" />
                        @if ($errors->has('cc.*'))
                            <p class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('cc.*') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group autocomplete-to">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input  col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="bcc">Bcc:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bcc" id="bcc" value="{{ old('bcc') ?: $mail->bcc() }}" />
                        @if ($errors->has('bcc.*'))
                            <p class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('bcc.*') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" value="{{ old('subject') ?: $mail->getSubject() }}" />
                        @if ($errors->has('subject'))
                            <p class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('subject') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="template">Email Template:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="template" v-model="template" v-on:change="loadTemplate()">
                            <option value="">None</option>
                            @foreach ($templates as $template)
                                <option value="{{ $template->id }}">{{ $template->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="content">Email Text:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
                        <main>
                            <div class="adjoined-bottom">
                                <div class="grid-container">
                                    <div class="grid-width-100">
                                        <textarea name="content" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"><?php  echo nl2br($mail->getBody()); ?></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </main>
                        @if ($errors->has('content'))
                            <p class="error-msg">{{ $errors->first('content') }}</p>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="email">File Upload:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <div class="attachments">
                            <input type="file" name="attachments[]" class="form-control" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="add-more-attachment">Add More</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>

                @if ($mail->getAction() == 'FORWARD' && ($mailModel = $mail->getInstance()))
                    <div class="gen-info mt20">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h3 class="subheading icon-open-close" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#locale-setting">Attachments</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12 collapse in" id="locale-setting">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <table class="table table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                            <th>File Name</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @if (($attachments = $mailModel->attachments) && !$attachments->isEmpty())
                                            @foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><a target="_blank" href="{{ url('public/attachments/' . $attachment->filename) }}" target="_blank">Preview</a></td>
                                                    <td>{{ $attachment->original_filename }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            @endforeach
                                        @else
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" align="center">No Attachments Found</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endif
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-form-label example-text-input col-sm-4 col-md-2" for="email"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button> &nbsp;
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{ url('superadmin/service-request/view/' . $ServiceRequest->id) }}">Discard</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and code for **controller**

```
 public function compose(ServiceRequest $ServiceRequest)
        {
            $templates = MailTemplate::where('org_id', $ServiceRequest->org_id)->get();
            $mail = new Compose($ServiceRequest);

            return view('admin.ServiceRequestEmails.compose')
                    ->with(compact('ServiceRequest', 'mail', 'templates'));
        }

        public function reply(MailModel $mail)
        {
            $ServiceRequest = $mail->ServiceRequest;
            $templates = MailTemplate::where('org_id', $ServiceRequest->org_id)->get();

            return view('admin.ServiceRequestEmails.compose')
                    ->with([
                        'templates' => $templates,
                        'mail' => new Reply($mail),
                        'ServiceRequest' => $ServiceRequest,
                    ]);
        }

        public function replyToAll(MailModel $mail)
        {
            $ServiceRequest = $mail->ServiceRequest;
    //print_r($ServiceRequest);

            $templates = MailTemplate::where('org_id', $ServiceRequest->org_id)->get();
    //print_r($templates);
    //die();
            return view('admin.ServiceRequestEmails.compose')
                    ->with([
                        'templates' => $templates,
                        'mail' => new ReplyToAll($mail),
                        'ServiceRequest' => $ServiceRequest,
                    ]);
        }

        public function forward(MailModel $mail)
        {
            $ServiceRequest = $mail->ServiceRequest;
            $templates = MailTemplate::where('org_id', $ServiceRequest->org_id)->get();

            return view('admin.ServiceRequestEmails.compose')
                    ->with([
                        'templates' => $templates,
                        'mail' => new Forward($mail),
                        'ServiceRequest' => $ServiceRequest,
                    ]);
        }

        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->request = $request;
            (new \App\Modicare\Validators\ServiceRequestEmailValidator($this->request))
                ->validate();

            $ServiceRequest = ServiceRequest::find($request->sr_id);
            $senderName = $this->getSenderNameByEmail($request->from);

        $this->mail = MailModel::create([
                'sr_id' => $request->sr_id,
                'parent_id' => $request->parent_id,
                'sender_name' => $senderName,
                'from' => $request->from,
                'to' => $request->to,
                'cc' => $request->cc,
                'bcc' => $request->bcc,
                'subject' => $request->subject,
                'body' => $request->content,
                'mca_no' => $ServiceRequest->mca_no,
                'sent_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'status' => 'SENT',
                'type' => 'OUT'
            ]);

            if ($request->parent_id && ($mail = MailModel::find($request->parent_id))) {
                $mail->status = 'REPLIED';
                $mail->save();
            }

            $mailSender = MailFacade::to(explode(',', $request->to));

            if ($request->cc) {
                $mailSender->cc(explode(',', $request->cc));
            }
            if ($request->bcc) {
                $mailSender->bcc(explode(',', $request->bcc));
            }

            if (!empty($request->attachments) && is_array($request->attachments))
            $files = $this->saveAttachments($request->attachments);
            $this->handleForwardMail();
            $mailSender->send(new ServiceRequestReply($this->mail));
            return redirect('superadmin/service-request/view/' . $request->sr_id);
        }

        private function getSenderNameByEmail($email)
        {
    //        $organizationEmail = OrganizationEmail::where('email', $email) -> orderBy ('id', 'desc')
    //;
            $organizationEmail = OrganizationEmail::where('email', $email)

                        ->first();
                    if ($organizationEmail) {
                        return $organizationEmail->organization->getName();
            }

            return Auth::User()->getName();
        }

        public function view(MailModel $mail)
        {
            if ($mail->status == 'NEW') {
                $mail->status = 'SEEN';
                $mail->save();
            }
            return view('admin.ServiceRequestEmails.view', compact('mail'));
        }

        public function print(MailModel $mail)
        {
            return view('admin.ServiceRequestEmails.print', compact('mail'));
        }

        private function handleForwardMail()
        {
            if ($this->request->action == 'FORWARD' && 
                ($parent = $this->mail->parent)) {

                foreach ($parent->attachments as $attachment) {
                    $newAttachment = $attachment->replicate();
                    $newAttachment->ref_id = $this->mail->id;
                    $newAttachment->save();
                }
            }
        }

        private function saveAttachments(array $attachments)
        {
            $files = [];
            foreach ($attachments as $key => $attachment) {
                $files[$key] = [
                    'newFilename' => $attachment->store('attachments', 'public'),
                    'originalFilename' => $attachment->getClientOriginalName(),
                ];

                Attachment::create($attachment->getRealPath(),[
                    'type' => 'MAIL',
                    'ref_id' => $this->mail->id,
                    'original_filename' => $attachment->getClientOriginalName(),
                    'filename' => basename($files[$key]['newFilename']),
                    'extn' => $attachment->getClientOriginalExtension(),
                    'mime_type' => $attachment->getClientMimeType(),
                    'size' => $attachment->getClientSize(),
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mail#introduction

Comment: Yes, but i am not able to find any help.

Comment: I am new to laravel and this code is third party code, so please let me know the line responsible for attachments

Comment: If you are using a third party service for handling emails then please edit your question and give more details about it. It should have its own documentation and we can't help without knowing what package you're using.